# Как начать подгружать картинку/видео(не скачивать) на сайте например по щелчку кнопки?

Tags: javascript, изображения, видео

Как начать подгружать картинку/видео(не скачивать) на сайте например по щелчку кнопки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elem1.onclick = function {
     elem2.innerHTML = '<img scr="img.jpg">';
}
```

Где elem1 - элемент, после клика на который начнется подгрузка
elem2 - блок, куда будет подгружаться

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете ввиду предварительное соединение, то вы можете использовать мета **preconnect**. Проверьте что **[Гугл говорит об этом](https://web.dev/uses-rel-preconnect/#improve-page-load-speed-with-preconnect)**:

> `<link rel="preconnect">` сообщает браузеру, что ваша страница
> намеревается установить соединение с другим источником и что вы
> хотите, чтобы процесс начался как можно скорее.

В этом случае браузер после загрузки веб-страницы, создаст предварительное соединение с вашим медиа-ресурсом и при активации кнопки ресурс загрузиться быстрее.